# MATLAB - Rotate an object with makehgtform - zrotate only around the origin

Tags: matlab, math, rotation, transform

I'm trying to use a slider and rotate a sphere in matlab. It works if the sphere is in the origin. but my sphere is at point (2.5,2.5,7.5) when I rotate it, the entire sphere rotates still around the origin. I want it to stay in the point and just spin.

My code: this is my slider function

```
function  slider_callback1(hObject, eventdata)
            s1 = get(slider, 'value');        
            R1 = makehgtform('zrotate', s1);
            set(t1, 'Matrix', R1);
            drawnow;
  end
```

Where

```
t1 = hgtransform;
set(sphere_1, 'Parent', t1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this is how I solved it:

```
function slider_callback1(hObject, eventdata)
    s1 = get(cabin, 'value');        
    R1 = makehgtform('zrotate', s1);

    R1(1,4) = 2.5;
    R1(2,4) = 2.5;
    R1(3,4) = 7.5;
    set(t1, 'Matrix', R1);

    s1 = floor(s1 * (180/pi) * 10)/10;
    set(sth1, 'String', num2str(s1));
    drawnow;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To rotate around an arbitrary point, you need three transforms; a translation to the origin, the rotation itself, and then a translation back.  These can of course be combined into a single 4D transform matrix.

I've never used `makehgtform`, but from the documentation it seems to have a `'translate'` option, which sounds like what you need.